# How do you limit FirebaseAdmob to specific Screens

Tags: firebase, dart, admob, flutter

I integrated AdMob with my flutter mobile application, however, although it was declared on a specific screen it shows up everywhere which makes chatting very difficult. is there a way to specify the screen on which we want the ads to be shown or at least hide them if detected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:
For anybody interested I was able to get around it by adding this to my application API:

Api.dart:

```
  FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: isIos ? ADDMOB_ADID_IOS : ADMOB_APPID_ANDROID);

   static BannerAd createBannerAd() {
    return new BannerAd(
      adUnitId: isIos 
                ? ADDMOB_ADID_IOS
                : ADDMOB_ADID_ANDROID,
      size: AdSize.smartBanner,
      targetingInfo: targetInfo,
      listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
        try {
          if (event == MobileAdEvent.loaded) {
            isAdShown = true;
          } else if (event == MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad) {
            isAdShown = false;
          } 
        } on Exception catch (error) {
          print('Error, ${error.toString()}');
        }

      }
    );
  }
```

And then I kept track of some variables:

Constants.dart:

```
bool isAdShown = false;
bool calledDisposed = false;
BannerAd banner;
```

So that when exiting the first screen I did this:

FirstScreen.dart:

```
      banner = TradeApi.createBannerAd()
        ..load()
        ..show().catchError(() => print('Error loading add'));
        isAdShown = true;

  if (isAdShown) {
                      await banner.dispose();
                      isAdShown = false;
                      calledDisposed = true; 
                    }
```

and then in my second screen:
SecondScreen.dart:

```
 appBar: new AppBar(
        leading: new WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () {
            if (!isAdShown && calledDisposed) {
              banner = TradeApi.createBannerAd();
              banner.load()..show();
              isAdShown = true;
              calledDisposed = false;
            }
            return Future<bool>.value(true);
          },
          child: const BackButton()        
        ),
      ),
```

That did the trick, I wasn't really sure if that was the most efficient way to do it but it worked